# Choosing item from dropdown menu with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

Hey I am trying to choose option from one site with javascript. No luck, I have tried couple of methods, but none seem to work. In this site http://www.finnkino.fi/movies/maxim_helsinki there is dropdown menu which says Tänään, 13.11.2010. I need to change to to another value from the menu with javascript. Help is highly appericiated! Thanks!

Comment: It could be much easier if you were using *real* HTML select elements instead of an imitation using JavaScript and divs. Then again, it wouldn't look as nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emulating the user's mouse clicks:

```
$('#dt_input').click();
$('#dt_input_14\\.11\\.2010').click();
```

Two backslashes are necessary before each dot because jQuery interprets the dot to refer to a specific HTML class; we need to escape the dots. Alternatively, use `document.getElementById`, which doesn't require the dots to be escaped:

```
$(document.getElementById('dt_input_14.11.2010')).click();
```

Comment: Using the selector won't work because jQuery will interpret the dots as class selectors.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the value of the `<select>` tag to some other value:

```
document.getElementById('dt').value = '08.01.2011';
```

This will select the option with `value="08.01.2011"`.

Or using jquery:

```
$('#dt').val('08.01.2011');
```